# Trying to tie the selection input so that I can press 1,2 or 3 and get my printed text options

Tags: python-3.x

```
def cSelection():
    Selection = input()
    return Selection

    if Selection == 1 :
       print('Oxygen levels are normal')
    elif Selection == 2:
        print('Fuel levels are at medium capacity')
    elif Selection == 3:
        print('Food is running low, request for new shipment')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement is not in right place. Your `if/elif` conditions don't running due to the `return` returns from the function before them. The `return` should be after the logic (`if/elif`).

Furthermore the `input()` function returns a string type but your `if/elif` contidions wait an integer. It means your should cast the output of `input()` to integer with `int()`.

I recommend to define an `else` branch if the input is not 1-3. Like in my below example.

**Correct code:**

```
def cSelection():
    Selection = int(input("Write a number (1-3): "))  # Input cast to integer.

    if Selection == 1 :
       print('Oxygen levels are normal')
    elif Selection == 2:
        print('Fuel levels are at medium capacity')
    elif Selection == 3:
        print('Food is running low, request for new shipment')
    else:
        print("Wrong option")

    return Selection

return_value = cSelection()
print("Return value of function: {}".format(return_value))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Write a number (1-3): 1
Oxygen levels are normal
Return value of function: 1

>>> python3 test.py 
Write a number (1-3): 3
Food is running low, request for new shipment
Return value of function: 3

>>> python3 test.py 
Write a number (1-3): 5
Wrong option
Return value of function: 5
```